# understand the figures in ubuntu command top

Tags: ubuntu

My `top` read like this. Could anyone tell me what is the meaning of `38863845d`, 
`5124095h` under the TIME+ column ? It cannot be days or hours. I am pretty sure
it hadn't run that long. Thanks.

```
top - 01:52:06 up 13 days, 11:26,  1 user,  load average: 3.88, 3.31, 3.15
Tasks: 207 total,   1 running, 206 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.5%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 84.2%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.2%st
Mem:   7340260k total,  5952860k used,  1387400k free,    10160k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   399204k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                
  569 mysql     20   0 3860m 2.9g 3644 S    5 41.8 38863845d mysqld                                                                 
 1259 www-data  20   0  355m  74m 2936 S    0  1.0 31171580d python                                                                 
  454 syslog    20   0  191m 1916  884 S    0  0.0 12596734d rsyslogd                                                               
15195 root      20   0  321m  36m 1528 S    0  0.5 56365051h console-kit-dae                                                        
12261 www-data  20   0  709m 241m 4664 S    0  3.4  5124095h apache2                                                                
12562 www-data  20   0  645m 179m 4612 S    0  2.5  5124095h apache2                                                                
12447 www-data  20   0  565m  98m 4604 S    4  1.4  5124095h apache2                                                                
  556 nobody    20   0  173m  40m  676 S    0  0.6  94:15.62 memcached
```

Comment: This seems like it's probably [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) because it is not about programming or software development. You might want to ask about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

The results you're seeing are the result of [a bug associated with some weird Xen kernels](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588769). They are meaningless.